# How can I hide code on mouseover in a category title in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

Either side of a category title I want to display an icon. Here is my code:

```
<i class="fa fa-tree" style="color: #fcae03;"></i> Christmas Hampers <i class="fa fa-tree" style="color: #fcae03;"></i>
```

The code works, but how can I make only 'Christmas Hampers' appear on mouseover?

My knowledge of code is limited, would someone mind being quite specific if they can assist me please? Thanks! :)

Comment: you should use some css or javascript. What have you tried since now? Can you post a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right you want to display only 2 tree icons and on mouseover (hover) to show 'Christmas Hampers'. Then try this code.

If you have some questions leave a comment :)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous"> <!-- Probably you don't need to apply this line -->

<div class="christmas-hampers-wrapper">
  <i class="fa fa-tree inline-block" style="color: #fcae03;"></i>
  <div class="christmas-hampers-wrapper inline-block">
    <div class="christmas-hampers">Christmas Hampers</div>
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-tree inline-block" style="color: #fcae03;"></i>
</div>
<style>
.inline-block{
  position: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
}
.christmas-hampers-wrapper > .christmas-hampers-wrapper{
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px; height: 18px;
  transition: .3s;
}
.christmas-hampers-wrapper > .christmas-hampers-wrapper > .christmas-hampers{
  width: 127px;
}
.christmas-hampers-wrapper:hover > .christmas-hampers-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 127px; height: 18px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain myself well enough. I want the menu title to show *tree* Christmas Hampers *tree* but when you hover the mouse over it I want it to only show 'Christmas Hampers' rather than all the code. Thank you for helping me :-)

Comment: Can you give me your social media or email

Comment: Thank you so much Kristers. Yes its rachelhlittle@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful :)